# Determine using Python if point is within a WGS84 polygon intersecting 180th meridian

Tags: python, software-recommendations, wgs84, point-in-polygon

I have a Python list of WGS84 points. Connecting these points together, we get two polygons on the WGS84 model of the Earth. I am interested in the smaller polygon which can possibly intersect 180th meridian and I would like to check if some given point is within it.

I am already aware of the solutions that work well for the cases where a polygon does not intersect 180th meridian such as
[Determine if point is within an irregular polygon using Python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/79215/determine-if-point-is-within-an-irregular-polygon-using-python)
or [Determining if coordinate is within polygon?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/274307/determining-if-coordinate-is-within-polygon)

I would like to get a library solution if possible so that I do not have to write additional tests for this function.